# Throttle Position Sensor Signals

Tags: electrical, throttle-position-sensor

I would like to study and discover more about the throttle position sensor that is installed in my car. The model of this tps sensor is called "cts 4089" and it has 6 pins. From what I read from the internet the sensor outputs two different signals 0-5V that indicates the position of the accelerator pedal.

I was trying out measuring the 2 signals using a multimeter and the voltage seems very unstable (the values in the video are recorded with the accelerator pedal not pushed). Also one is lower than the other. I will attach the link of the two video showing the two TPS signal measured with the multimeter.

- Signal 1: [Video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=74BFg-F47Ew)
- Signal 2: [Video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=PhHpNinmi-A)
- How I can determine the range of the two signals (accelerator pedal
  up or accelerator pedal down)?
- Why the voltage is so unstable?

Comment: how do you know that the output is steady voltage? ... use an oscilloscope

Comment: Have you checked the reference voltage?  Does your multimeter show it is stable?

Comment: You should be able to do this test without the engine running, but with the ignition on.  Then just move the pedal its full range.

Comment: Did you see this when you searched online?
https://www.electriciansforums.net/threads/throttle-position-sensor.196092/
Or this? https://fispa.it/sites/all/files/allegati/84.2081_Ita_Eng_(99.8001).pdf

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to find out thanks to this pdf: fispa.it/sites/all/files/allegati/84.2081_Ita_Eng_(99.8001).pdf the two signal cables, I was wrong when I did the measurements that's why the voltage did not make sense and was not stable.

For everyone who has and wants to know the signals of the CTS 4089 throttle position sensor I will share it in this post:

- Singal 1 (APP 1): Pin 2 and 6, Signal range measured(0.31 V no accelerator pushed - 1.74 V accelerator pushed all the way down)
- Signal 2 (APP 2): Pin 2 and 5, Signal range measured(0.62 V no accelerator pushed - 3.42 V accelerator pushed all the way down)